# How to scroll the circle using mouse wheel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, gsap

I have one circle and I have to rotate 360 deg using mouse scroll wheel or arrow but it will start when circle touches the blue border. Now my code is working when I scroll it and touch the blue border. But I have to scroll the circle using the mouse wheel. I mean using mouse wheel I have to rotate the circle also reverse.

Is there any idea how to do that?

```js
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
  var l_360 = document.getElementById("l_360");
  var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();
  var tween = TweenLite.to(l_360, 3, {
    x: -1910,
    y: 350,
    rotation: 360,
    opacity: '1',
    ease: Linear.easeOut
  });
  var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
      triggerElement: "#l_360"
    })
    .setTween(tween)
    .setClassToggle('#l_360', 'fade-in')
    .addTo(controller);

});
```

```css
.parent_img {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
}

.content,
.content_2,
.content_3 {
  width: 700px;
  position: relative;
}

.content {
  margin-top: 400px;
}

.main_l {
  position: fixed;
  right: 115px;
  top: 20px;
  z-index: 100;
}

.main_l .l_circle {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: #EFBD40;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
}

.main_l .l_circle h2 {
  margin: auto;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 35px;
}

.blue {
  background-color: #0082ff;
  transform: skew(0deg, -10deg);
  z-index: -1;
  /*color: #fff;*/
}

.blue .container {
  transform: skew(0deg, 10deg);
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_l" id="l_360">
  <div class="l_circle">
    <h2>360 circle</h2>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="blue">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">
      <h2>This is just for testing</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.3/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.3/plugins/ScrollToPlugin.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.2/plugins/CSSPlugin.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/ScrollMagic.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/plugins/animation.gsap.js"></script>
```

Comment: are u looking for the circle to be in one place and for it to rotate when using scroll?

Comment: @Hash, That correct. circle Is fixed now and when user scrolls  then circle touch the blue color and using mouse wheel that circle will run like a tier.

Comment: If you open [The Official ScrollMagic Documentation](http://scrollmagic.io/docs/ScrollMagic.Scene.html#constructor) you will see that there is an option to `reverse` described as **Should the scene reverse, when scrolling up?**, and I think this is what you are looking for, but I don't know actually how to implement it.

Comment: @AlaaMh, Thanks for the reply, I just want to know how to use that one also. I uploaded question here if you can help me out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47573577/how-to-use-scrollmagic

Answer (score 1):

Using the [wheel](https://devdocs.io/dom/wheelevent) event will give you deltas for the direction you scroll the wheel. For example, to detect a vertical wheel movement the property `deltaY` will be either a negative value (forward) or positive (backward):

You can use the value directly if you wish, but it may vary depending on browser and system.

**Example**

```js
var div = document.querySelector("div");
var angle = 0;
document.onwheel = function(e) {
  if (e.deltaY) {                   // we have a wheel for vertical (common) direction
    e.preventDefault();
    angle += e.deltaY < 0 ? 4 : -4; // what direction?
    div.style.transform = "rotate(" + angle + "deg)"; // do something
  }
};
```

```css
body {margin:30px}
div {border-radius:50%;border:3px solid #09f;width:150px;height:150px;}
```

```html
<div> O</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. https://codepen.io/Narendra_verma/pen/eePaPe?editors=1010 I added my code here. and I tried your code but in this only inside text of the circle is rotating.

Comment: @NarendraVerma I'm not gonna code it for you :) You have all the information you need on how to use it, now it's your job to apply this information to your scenario.

Comment: I really appreciate, you trying to solve my issue. I haven't got any idea from your code to implement it.